# Cartesian coordinates to Cylindrical coordinates

Tags: physics, coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

> The position vector, as a function of time and in Cartesian coordinates, of a particle is the following:
>
> $$\vec{r}(t) = (5t^2-6t)\vec{e}_1 + \cos(\sin(t))\vec{e}_2+ (8t-5)\vec{e}_3$$

I have that vector expressed in Cartesian coordinates, how it would be expressed in cylindrical coordinates. I've read many manuals and seen videos, but I can't understand it. If you want to do it with this vector instead, you can do it with another one.

I know it seems like a more appropriate question for the Physics forum, but from there I have been referred here.

Comment: Use the conversion formulas: $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$.

Comment: And what about the z-coordinate? @Nick

Comment: The $z$-coordinate doesn't change in cylindrical coordinates. The cylindrical coordinate system is $(r,\theta,z)$, where $z$ is the same from Cartesian coordinates, and $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates in the $x,y$-directions.

Comment: So, getting polar and cylindrical coordinates is very similar, isn't it? @Nick

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same.